# Deleting data from Recycler View list using Google Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an app that is connected to Firestore that allows users to add and remove TV show data from the Recycler View list. My problem is trying to get data to be removed from the list by having an activity asking the user for the name, director, and viewership of the show.  After I have entered the info for the activity and pushed the button, it does not remove the info from the list and is still there.
[Activity that allows you to remove data from Recycler View list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmGX1.jpg)

As for the code.

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    data = ArrayList<TV>()

    tvAdapter = TVAdapter(data)

    var removeTV = findViewById(R.id.removeButton) as Button    //Button that removes data after       user enters rest of data.
    var name = findViewById(R.id.editTextShowName2) as EditText //Shows name
    var dir = findViewById(R.id.editTextDirector2) as EditText  //Shows director
    var view = findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber2) as EditText   //Shows viewership

    removeTV.setOnClickListener{
        val showN = name.text.toString()
        val d = dir.text.toString()
        val v = view.text.toString()
        
        // Section for making notifications when user removes data from RV list
        val intent = Intent(this, AddShowActivity::class.java).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        }
        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

        var builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "CHANNEL_ID")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_message)
            .setContentTitle("Notification")
            .setContentText("Show Removed!")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)

        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build())
        // End of notification Section

        val data = hashMapOf(
            "name" to "${showN}",
            "director" to "${d}",
            "viewership" to "${v}"
        )
        
        // Google Firebase that suppose to remove data from list and any data from collection that is there.
        db.collection("ProjectTVShows").document("-") //Want it to remove data that the user                entered from the Removing Activity.
            .delete()
            .addOnSuccessListener { documentReference ->
                Log.d("MY DEBUG", "DocumentSnapshot removed with ID")

                tvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

                var data1 = name.text.toString()
                var data2 = dir.text.toString()
                var data3 = view.text.toString()
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.w("MY DEBUG", "Error adding document", e)
            }

        finish() //After button is pressed it goes back to the main activity.
    }
}

private fun createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val name = "Channel Name"
        val descriptionText = "Channel Description"
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        val channel = NotificationChannel("CHANNEL_ID", name, importance).apply {
            description = descriptionText
        }
        // Register the channel with the system
        val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}
```

}

I have tried looking for documentation on Google and watching videos online to see if I can find any similarity to my issue.  Also tried changing the code multiple times.

Comment: I cannot spot the issue in your code, but here are some resources ([1](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) & [2](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166)) that might help.

Comment: The problem that I am having is when after I put the info for the remove activity and push the button does not delete the data from the list.

Comment: Is any of the listeners triggered?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Is `onSuccess` or `onFailure` even triggered?

Comment: They do trigger actually, I keep getting DocumentSnapshot removed with ID:null.  Whenever I do the remove activity.

Comment: What do you mean by "DocumentSnapshot removed with ID:null"?

Comment: In the code in the onSuccess it says the ID for .delete() in db.collection.document() has an invalid ID for when trying to remove data.

Comment: Can you please show us a screenshot of the document that you want to remove?

Comment: Please show us a more detailed screenshot that includes the collection name and document ID.

Comment: Document id is SmRYuGol1R88vqLfD2VR and the collection name is ProjectTVShows

Answer (score 0):

When you call `delete()` on the following document reference:

```
db.collection("ProjectTVShows").document("-").delete()
//
```

It means that you want to delete a document that has the ID of `-`, an operation that cannot be performed since there is no document that has such an ID. If you want to delete the document that has the `SmRYuGol1R88vqLfD2VR` ID, then you should pass that ID to the `document()` method:

```
db.collection("ProjectTVShows").document("SmRYuGol1R88vqLfD2VR").delete()
//
```

Comment: Hey there. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?

Comment: That's not what I am trying to do I want my remove activity to remove any show that I type into the edit texts.  That would only delete that one specific show.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I did not understand your last comment.

Comment: I want to use my remove activity screenshot above to be able to remove data on the list that I enter into it not just that specific one.

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) or even this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166) might help, right?

Comment: Can I help you with other information?

Comment: For your second link it won't let me view the whole article without paying.